# Convert the following urlString to encoded urlString in Swift 3.0

Tags: swift, url, swift3, nsurl, url-encoding

The following `URL` need to be encode in Swift 3

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=madhapur.%20Hyderabad

Comment: You need to start accepting answer that helps you never accept single answer. Please have look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/…. This will add reputation to you and author of the post.

Answer (score 1):

You can encode and decode the URL like this.

```
let stringURL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=madhapur Hyderabad"
if let encodeURL = stringURL.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed) {
    print(encodeURL)
    let decodeURL = encodeURL.removingPercentEncoding
    print(decodeURL)
}
```

**Output**

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=madhapur%20Hyderabad
Optional("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=madhapur Hyderabad")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use  **removingPercentEncoding**

```
var str = "https:%2F%2Fmaps.googleapis.com%2Fmaps%2Fapi%2Fgeocode%2Fjson%3Faddress=madhapur.%20Hyderabad"
str = str.removingPercentEncoding!
```

Result:- [https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=madhapur. Hyderabad](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=madhapur.%20Hyderabad)

Comment: Sorry, actual question is now i posted, please see it again